# VS2013 displays incorrect configuration in property page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

### Short version

VS2013, switching property page views of files to a certain configuration shows the wrong configuration!

### Long version

I have a solution with several projects, each project containing a "Debug", "DebugRelease", and "Release" configuration.

- For the projects, viewing the properties in the property page viewer (right click, choose "Properties") displays the configuration settings corectly.
- For individual files, viewing the properties in the property page viewer looks correct in Release, looks correct in DebugRelease, and Debug seems to display the same properties as DebugRelease.
- In fact, making any changes and saving them causes the project XML to make changes for "DebugRelease". Additionally, making changes in "Debug" causes "DebugRelease" to change as well... Seems like "Debug" for some reason isn't being displayed.
- Compiling seems to compile to DebugRelease as well, even though the solution configuration is set to use Debug across all projects.
- If I rename the "Debug" configuration to something that's not a prefix of "DebugRelease" it seems to work okay. If I rename it to a prefix, however, the same problem persists.
- More vexing still, I have other project configuration names that are similar (BlahBlah_Debug, BlahBlah_DebugRelease, and BlahBlah_Release) and only some of those display similar behavior -- some of them work fine.

Problem first noticed under VS2013.4. Updated to VS2013.5 and it still persists. This didn't used to be an issue.

The obvious work around is to rename the project configurations, but there's a decent amount of tooling that expects the configurations as they already are.

Comment: I'd go through the project settings of two of these linked Debug / DebugRelease line by line to see if you've accidentally pointed them to some of the same make / config / build / post-build files.  I can't point to a specific setting to check, I'm just saying there has to be **something** shared by the two configurations to link them like that.

Comment: @Dave, I agree, and to the best of my ability I've actually combed all of the build properties, vcxproj, and sln files, trying to see any correlation. Alas, no luck -- maybe I'm looking in the wrong spot, but maybe I just overlooked it.. Lots of XML/text to go through. :)

Comment: At some point you might want to just add a new configuration that is NOT based on any existing configuration and set the properties by hand.

Comment: I was in the process of migrating to VS2017 anyway, and this buggy behavior ceased to display in VS2017. Case closed, even if not solved.